# What was the first Hokage's disease?

Tags: naruto

Hashirama Senju, a reincarnation of one of the sage of six paths son (Asura) and the only kage who Madara didn't ignore is one of the most overpowered characters in Naruto. Being so powerful (the authors had to make it so that) he had to die of a disease (as anyone who could beat him would have to be stronger than Madara). This is not just a theory as it is confirmed further by one of the data books, can someone help me find where exactly that is stated and what exactly was his disease?